# Outlook Rule with script keeps repeating

Tags: email, vba, vbscript, outlook, gmail

I am trying to run a rule in outlook that will forward any new mail that comes into a specific account that will change the subject line and forward the mail to a different account.

I have set up a rule that applies the rule after the message has arrived, which has an attachment, and on this machine only run Project1.ThisOutlookSession.SubjForward
except if message body contain 'certain text'

The script looks like this

```
Sub SubjForward(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Item.Subject = "New Subject"
Item.Save

Set myForward = Item.Forward
myForward.Recipients.Add "forwardmail@domain.com"

myForward.DeleteAfterSubmit = True

myForward.Send

End Sub
```

The rule forwards the message to the new address fine but it keeps on forwarding the same email until I kill the script.

Dose anyone know where I am going wrong?

**I have updated further details in the comments below, thanks**

Comment: I can't see any obvious reason from your code, you could look at checking the item is "Unread" before forwarding and then mark it as "Read" at the end of the sub so that it doesn't get picked up again.

Comment: Do you have any other defaults setup within Outlook? (i.e. CC yourself on all messages, etc.)

Comment: Is that `Different Account` also configured with same outlook?

Comment: Matt, thanks I will try that, altough I cant see why it would be necessary. Gaffi, no other defaults that would suggest multiple forwarding would occur that I can see. Siddharth, the different account is a gmail account but is not conifgured with my outlook. The mail gets sent to the my Personal Folders -> Outbox folder and then gets sent but the mail then keeps getting put into that outbox folder and sent over and over again.

Comment: Do you have other rules also applied to all incoming messages? You might try making this the first rule applied to the message and then add "Stop processing more rules" to see if other rules are causing recursion.

Comment: The only other rule I have is the 'clear categories on mail' rule.

Comment: Just to update, it appears to keep sending until the original email appears in the inbox (its a gmail account so I can see that it is in the inbox on the web but it takes longer to appear in the inbox in outlook)

Comment: Tried the following for Matt's suggestion but it didnt work (and never gets marked a read) I presume I have something wrong. Im very new to scripting for outlook.                                                                                                                            `Sub SubjForward(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

If (Item.UnRead) Then`

     _original code_ 
    `Item.UnRead = False
    Item.Save
End If`

Comment: @Henrick I think rather than using a rule, you would perhaps be better making use of the applications built in events (NewMail or NewMailEx, depending on the version of outlook) as these fire when new item's arrive in the inbox and may be more stable than using client created rules.

Comment: I stripped back the script to just `Sub ChangeSubjectForward(Item As Outlook.MailItem) Item.Subject = "Test 9"
    Set myForward = Item.Forward
    myForward.Recipients.Add "test@domain.com"
 myForward.Send                                                   end Sub` . It works fine except when coming from a gmail account (yahoo,hotmail etc work fine). The account using outlook to auto forward the mail is also a gmail account. So it appears gmail to gmail is causing a problem. The mail comes in to the inbox, forwards to the outbox then disappears from the inbox and repeats until script is killed

Comment: Is this a 'feature' in GMail? did they fix it yet? Have you found a workaround? Or is the problem still outstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ItemAdd Event handler, this way your script will only run when a new 'item' is added to your inbox ie. when you receive the mail.

Alternatively, I cannot see a need to use VBA at all really here? You could just set up a rule on outlook to forward the message?

Regards
Paul

Comment: Try Sub SubjForward_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) instead of Sub SubjForward(Item As Outlook.MailItem)